# JavaScript let Block-Scope in Firefox Developer Tools Debug View

Tags: javascript

I'm looking into the working of the `let` *block scope* in JavaScript, in particular how the debug views of the browsers display the information

Using `let` within a `for` loop creates a *block-scope*, which the callback `function timeoutHandler()` has access to, all is good with this

In **Chrome Dev Tools**, the [[Scopes]] look as follows:

[image]

In **Firefox Developer Tools**, there is an extra Block Scope listed, which has `timeoutHandler:timeoutHandler()` as it's property. I only expected to see the Block Scope with `j:1`

[image]

What is this extra Block referring to?

Just wondering, as the lexical scopes I expected are shown in the Chrome debug, but not as expected in Firefox debug

Comment: I am by no means an expert in js, but as I see it it's the block where `let j` is defined - that would be the `for {...}` block

Comment: @birdspider yes, but there are 2 blocks in the Firefox view. It's the other block I'm asking about

Comment: hm, the only thing that comes to mind is that the JS file/snippet gets it own overarching block (topmost/root block?) - which FF displays - but I didn't find any hard facts/standards for it - I checked [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-lexical-environments) but got lost fast

Answer (score 0):

> What is this extra Block with `timeoutHandler` referring to?

It seems to show the [immutable binding that is wrapped around your *named function expression*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30547514/1048572). The function expression is actually interpreted as if your code was

```
'use strict';

for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    let j = i;
    setTimeout( {
        const timeoutHandler = function() {
            console.log(j);
            debugger;
        };
        timeoutHandler
    }, 1000);
}
```

(OK, this block scope inside the call expression is obviously not syntactically valid, but I hope you get the meaning)