# What are the block scopes in the debugger?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I wrote a small code to see how the call stack and scopes work in steps:

```
function foo(){
  debugger;
  bar();
  function bar(){
    thi();
    function thi(){
      var y = 20;
    }
  }
}
foo();
```

Here is the screen from the Firefox debugger:
[image]

The question is what are the scopes called 'block? If we look into them, we can see that these are the scopes of 'bar' and 'thi' functions. But, why are they signed with the word "block"?

Comment: What debugger are you using? It seems to be confused, as obviously in your code there are only function scopes.

Comment: @Bergi judging from the UI, looks like firefox.

Comment: What line did you break at when this view is show? Doesn't appear to be the `debugger` one. Did you step manually?

Comment: Looks like someone else asked pretty much the same question 16 days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426956/javascript-let-block-scope-in-firefox-developer-tools-debug-view

Comment: @Bergi I can reproduce this if I set a breakpoint on the `var y = 20` line and take one step. It's definitely paused within the `thi` function.

Comment: @Bergi, I use the debugger of firefox.

Comment: @JLRishe, you are right, it's paused within the thi func

Comment: @JLRishe Not exactly. I could answer that one but not this here.

Comment: Hm, `thi: (optimised away)` might give a hint on why the upper block is not a function scope, but still it should show `bar` somewhere. Unless that was inlined as well?

Comment: Isn't that a "block scope" introduced by ES6 ?